# Win32: Storing Multi-Line Text in a Buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

How would I go about displaying multi-line text in Win32? This code is within my **GamePaint()** function, and I want to write the top 5 High Scores (stored in an attribute of a struct) out to the screen. I can get it to successfully output a single line using this method...how do I make the TCHAR buffer, szText, store multiple lines? Here's what I've attempted so far:

**Original Code:**

```
    //draw rect for normal scores
ChangeTextFormat(hDC, hWnd, 1);
TCHAR szText[64];
RECT  rcNormalScores = { 268, 122, 436, 330};
RECT  rcHardScores = { 37, 122, 198, 330};

//stringstream ssTemp;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    //ssTemp << i;

    //display nth Normal score
    wsprintf(szText, "%d \n", g_scoreTop[i].num);
    DrawText(hDC, szText, -1, &rcNormalScores, DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK);

}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the info, but I'm still having some difficulty converting between data types. Here's the error I'm getting:

> cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

EDIT2: Thanks for the help, queen3. I've posted the working code below:

**Working Code:**

```
ChangeTextFormat(hDC, hWnd, 1);
RECT  rcNormalScores = { 37, 122, 198, 330}; 
RECT  rcHardScores = { 268, 122, 436, 330};

stringstream ssTemp;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ssTemp << g_scoreTop[i].num << " \n";
}

string sTemp = ssTemp.str();
LPCSTR LPTemp = (LPCSTR)sTemp.c_str();

DrawText(hDC, LPTemp, -1, &rcNormalScores, DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK);
DrawText(hDC, LPTemp, -1, &rcHardScores, DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK);
```

Comment: There's nothing after the newline. What exactly were you expecting to see?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: There are four more numbers and newlines after it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No there are not. He's outputting each line to the beginning of the buffer so it will only ever have one line.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: That is the problem, and queen3's answer is the solution. I am answering _your_ question of what the OP expected to see, which is five lines of numbers.

Comment: I'll also suggest using wstring (and wstringstream) instead of fixed length buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either of

1. Make one string with all lines and newlines and do single DrawText
2. Adjust rcNormalScores .top each time by adding height of the string (for this you can use DT_CALCRECT flag)

The first one might work better if you later decide to change DT_LEFT to DT_CENTER.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've attempted to implement that solution, but am getting a strange casting error. I've put both the error & updated code in the OP, if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: If you use wstringstream then use wstring, not string, and LPCWSTR not LPCSTR.